# Use Knockout Non-Metallic Push-In Connector for NM Cable Clamps?

Tags: cables, cable-management

I'm getting ready to install NM cable clamps in recessed lighting cans:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-6-in-Aluminum-Remodel-IC-Recessed-Can-Light-Housing-6-Pack-CAT7ICRM/202057577

While looking for the various suitable clamps I also found the following:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-1-2-in-Knockout-Non-Metallic-Push-In-Connector-100-Pack-75105B/100150300

I've been looking through the various NEC2020 Edition chapters and didn't see anything that specifies precisely what a clamp should "look like".
Is it ok to use push in connectors to fulfill the requirement for cable clamps?
It would make life easier for me, so I'm guessing it's not ok.

Comment: have you read the installation instructions?

Comment: I don't know if it's ok but if you're installing lights with their own junction box that does not get attached to a joist the screw down metal ones are a good idea.  They do a better job at isolating the electrical connections from movement from outside the box

Comment: You need to use listed products in accordance with their instructions and labeling.

Comment: RTFM.  No clamps needed—use the locking slot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When my electrician was replacing my panel, he used both the plastic type that you linked and the traditional ones [like these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208):

[image: metal clamp]

Just make sure whatever you get is sized to match the knockouts in your boxes. If you have more than one cable (e.g., in + out) then check the specs to see if you can use two cables in one clamp.